# Checkboxes checked if values exists on the mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have this table,

```
--------------------------------------------
|   products_id   |   related_products_ids |
| ------------------------------------------
|    1            |   2                    |
|    1            |   3                    |
|    1            |   4                    |
--------------------------------------------
```

**Problem 1**

I have these checkboxes,

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category1"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 1
<input value="2" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category2"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 2
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 3
<input value="3" type="checkbox" name="rp_product[]" id="in-category3"> Microsoft IntelliMouse Pro 4
```

I used this code,

```
<?php
echo '<ul id="categorychecklist" class="list:category categorychecklist form-no-clear">';
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT related_products_ids FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." where products_id = '" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['pID']."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$rp_sql = "select products_id, products_name from ".TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION." where products_id !='" . (int)$HTTP_GET_VARS['pID']."' order by products_name";
$rp_1 = mysql_query($rp_sql);
while($rp_2 = mysql_fetch_array($rp_1)) {
    $checked = '';
    if ($row['related_products_ids'] == $rp_2['products_id']) $checked = " checked";
    echo "<li id=\"category-".$rp_2['products_id']."\" class=\"popular-category\"><label class=\"selectit\"><input value=\"".$rp_2['products_id']."\" type=\"checkbox\" name=\"rp_product[]\" class=\"rp_item\"" . $checked . "> <span>".$rp_2['products_name']."</span></label></li>";
}
mysql_free_result($rp_1);
echo '</ul></div></div>';
?>
```

But my php code is not working, only 1 checkbox is checked. How can i make those checkboxes `checked` if their value exist on the database table?

**Problem 2**

I also wanted to output the related products by products ids,

I used this code,

```
$sql = "SELECT related_products_ids FROM ".TABLE_RELATED_PRODUCTS." where products_id = '" . (int)$_GET["products_id"]."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$lst_rp = explode(',', $row['related_products_ids']);
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))){
echo '<ul id="related-products-array">';
foreach($lst_rp as $rp_id) {
    $res = "select p.products_id, products_type, pd.products_name, pd.products_description, p.products_model, p.products_quantity, p.products_image, pd.products_url, p.products_price, p.products_tax_class_id, p.products_date_added, p.products_date_available, p.manufacturers_id from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd where p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = '" . $rp_id . "' and pd.products_id = p.products_id and pd.language_id = '" . (int)$languages_id . "'";
    $result1 = mysql_query($res);
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
     if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($res))){
       if ($nw_price = tep_get_products_special_price($rp_id)) {
        $products_price1 = '<del>' . $currencies->display_price($row1['products_price'], tep_get_tax_rate($row1['products_tax_class_id'])) . '</del><br><span class="productSpecialPrice">' . $currencies->display_price($nw_price, tep_get_tax_rate($row1['products_tax_class_id'])) . '</span>';
       } else {
        $products_price1 = $currencies->display_price($row1['products_price'], tep_get_tax_rate($row1['products_tax_class_id']));
       }
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($storepage).'?slug=product_info.php&products_id='.$rp_id.'" target="_blank">'.tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $row1['products_image'], addslashes($row1['products_name']), null, null, 'hspace="5" vspace="5" height="120" width="120"').'<br>'.$row1['products_name'].'</a><br>'.$products_price1.'</li>';
     } else {
     }

}
echo '</ul>';
} else {
echo 'No related products.';
}
echo '<div style="clear:both;"></div>';
```

Only one related product is displayed. I know there is something wrong with my code, I just can't figure it out.

Please Help.

Comment: This is off topic, but I think you could strongly benefit from the use of sprintf / printf for building strings.  It would make the above code much easier to write, read, and maintain.

Comment: http_get_vars is deprecated, and you shouldn't be using it at all in any new code. These days it's `$_GET`. You're also running your queries multiple times, which is inefficient, and assuming they've succeeded, which is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to do this:

```
function isChecked() {
    # perform SQL query
    # if value exists, set $exists to true
    if ($exists) {
        return "checked";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

<input type="checkbox" <?php echo isChecked() ?> />
```

Obviously, you would need to adjust your code, maybe put the whole input tag in a loop in php and write 'checked' or not depending on your query. But the key is:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked /> Checked by default
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://notfound.stackexchange.com/">`enter code here`
<?php $row9=mysql_query("select * from project_cat where des!=''");?>
Please Select How Did They Do It: <br/>
<?php
$query=mysql_query("select * from addproject where page_name='HOW DID THEY DO IT' order by id desc limit 0,1");
$get=mysql_fetch_array($query);
$check=$get['add_project'];
while($sql9=mysql_fetch_assoc($row9)) {     
    if($check==$sql9['project']) {?>    
    <input type="radio" name="project" value="<?php echo $sql9['project']; ?>" checked="checked" /><?php echo $sql9['project']; ?><br/> 
    <?php } else {?>
        <input type="radio" name="project" value="<?php echo $sql9['project']; ?>"/><?php echo $sql9['project']; ?><br/>    
    <?php } } ?></a>
```

Comment: Mind to add some words of explanation?